# How to show that $e^{-\frac{1}{x}}<x^n$ within $0<x<\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I would just like to show that, given a positive integer $n$, it is possible to find a positive real number $\delta$ such that

$$e^{-\frac{1}{x}}<x^n,~~~~0<x<\delta$$

For various values of $n$, I have checked numerically that this is true, but I just don't know how to prove it. I've thought of expanding the exponential  into a series of some sort that converges monotonically, and then truncating that series to obtain the inequality, but I haven't got any luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y=\frac{1}{x}$, and you are asking, given a positive integer $n$, is it possible to find a positive real number $\rho$ (the reciprocal of $\delta$) such that $$e^{-y}<\frac{1}{y^n},\qquad y>\rho$$
In other words, for large enough $y$ is $$\frac{y^n}{e^{y}}<1\text{?}$$ And the answer is yes, because repeated iteration of L'Hospital's Rule shows that $$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{y^n}{e^{y}}=0\text{.}$$

---

Alternatively, apply $\ln$ and multiply by $x$, and you are asking, given a positive integer $n$, is it possible to find a positive real number $\delta$ such that $$-1<nx\ln(x)\qquad0<x<\delta$$ and again the answer is yes because $$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}x\ln(x)=0\text{.}$$ One way to show this is to write it as $$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^{-1}}$$ and use L'Hospital's Rule once.

Comment: I don't understand how the second equation (inequality) is validated by the last equation (limit).

Comment: @ArturodonJuan If the limit is $0$, that means that $y^n/e^y$ is within $\epsilon$ of $0$ for all $y$ larger than $\rho$. If you are arbitrarily close to $0$, you must be less than $1$.

Answer (score 3):

A direct way. For $x>0$,
$$e^{\frac{1}{x}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!x^k}>\frac{1}{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}.$$
Therefore
$$x^ne^{\frac{1}{x}}>\frac{x^n}{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!x}> 1$$
as soon as $0<x<\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. Hence
$e^{-\frac{1}{x}}<x^n$ for $0<x<\delta:=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.